# How to find out which user credentials were used to connect to a SMB share

Tags: windows, networking, samba, smb, windows-server

I am currently running a Windows 7 client with a mapped network drive Z: to \someserver\someshare, which I can see in explorer. How can I find out which user account was actually used to create this mapping?

So what I am asking for is: I already have a mapped network drive, but want to know afterwards which user was used to connect.

I can see in properties of course what server I am connected to, but not which credentials were actually used to connect to that share on a server. Is there a way using the net command, or something similar?

Answer (score 3):

#### I already have a mapped network drive, but want to know afterwards which user was used to connect.

Try looking at the event logs for [EventID 5140: A network share object was accessed](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=5140):

**5140: A network share object was accessed**

> Subject:
>
> The user and logon session that accessed the share.
>
> - Security ID:  The SID of the account.
> - Account Name: The account logon name.
> - Account Domain: The domain or - in the case of local accounts - computer name.
>     Logon ID is a semi-unique (unique between reboots) number that identifies the logon session.  Logon ID allows you to correlate
>     backwards to the logon event (4624) as well as with other events
>     logged during the same logon session.

...

**Examples of 5140**

```
A network share object was accessed.

Subject:

   Security ID:  ACME-FR\Administrator
   Account Name:  Administrator
   Account Domain:  ACME-FR
   Logon ID:  0x74a739

Network Information:

   Source Address:  10.42.42.221
   Source Port:  65097

Share Name:   \\*\Dharma Initiative Protocols
```